# How can I keep track of an int and hold the 0's

Tags: java

Java question, 
Say I have a number such as 0000102 and the 0s are important, as in they need to be there.

How can I save this information in an int(or some other way that would allow me to increment it)

For example, after checking the number 0000102 it would then add one to it and check for 0000103

When I try saving it as in int it just reverts to 102 and gets rid of the 0's, and therefore doesn't match as I search through a database since it is no longer the same. Does anyone know of a way I can do this without it removing the 0's. Thanks

EDIT:

My final solution for addition with leading zeros was this function, it takes a string with leading 0's adds one to it, then returns the string

```
String nextNum(String s){
    int number =0;
    String newNum =""; 
    int len = s.length();
    int newLength =0;
    for(int i =0; i < s.length()-1; i++){
      if (s.charAt(i) == '0')
        newNum+="0";
        else 
        break;      
    }
     number = Integer.parseInt(s);
     number++;
     newNum +=  String.valueOf(number);
     newLength = newNum.length();
     if(newLength == len)
    return newNum;
     else
    return newNum.substring(1); //incase number was 000099 it doesnt go to   0000100 it goes to   000100 instead 
  }
```

Comment: How do you get the input? as a String?

Comment: I can get it any way, ideally as a string read from a text file. But if needed it can be hard coded in the program as any type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use string formatting by combining `printf` with `"%0d"` as follows:

```
    String num = "000123";
    Integer n = Integer.parseInt(num);
    n++;
    int len = num.length();
    System.out.printf("%0" + len + "d", n); //  000124

    // and if you want to store the result
    // back into a string:
    String res = String.format("%0" + len + "d", n);
    System.out.println(res); // 000124
```

Comment: So instead of printing it out (since thats not what the program does). can it store it back into a string after updating it? And would it be as simple as num = ("%0" + len + "d", n); Or would that not work. Since the number needs to be stored after updated, not printed.

Comment: @Lain yes you can do that using `String.format()` - I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks:) Ill give you best answer:P But since I was unsure I ended up writing my own function for it, think ill post it in my question for peoples future reference also

Answer (score 1):

The number itself is separate from the representation of the number. The number associated with what we usually call "ten" is always the quantity that counts these: ||||||||||, but it has many possible string representations: "10", "0000010", "0x0a", "1010(2)"... (not all of these are valid Java representations, just various representations that humans are using)

Your number will always be stored in the computer in such a way that the quantity can be (mostly) accurately handled. The string representation is normally not stored; it is calculated each time. For example, when you do `System.out.println(102)`, it is actually handled as `System.out.println(Integer.toString(102, 10))`.

Between `102` and `"0000102"`, figure which one you want to store and which one you want to display, and convert appropriately when you need the other one.

Comment: Not quite, 0000102 == 66 (it's parsed as octal *when it appears in source code*)

Answer (score 1):

You would store the value as an int (without zeroes) but could convert it into a String with leading zeroes when you want to print or display it. Here is an example conversion method.

```
public String addZeroes(int value, int desiredLength) {
    String valueString = value + "";
    int valueLength = valueString.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < desiredLength - valueLength; i++) {
        valueString = "0" + valueString;
    }

    return valueString;
}
```

Comment: There are better ways to add leading zeroes, like `String.format` or `DecimalFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `String`.

The decimal numbers `000102` and `0102` and `102` (and for that matter, the hex number `0x66`) are all the same integer value, there is no way to distinguish between them once you store them as an `int`.

If you want to preserve a specific character representation of your integer, then you need a string.

To increment the String you'll need to parse it to an Integer, and then reformat it.

```
String increment(String s) {
  int n = Integer.parseInt(s, 10)
  return ("%0" + s.length() + "d").format(n+1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you need to keep track of the leading zeroes, but that's separate from the number itself. I would keep the number itself as an `int`, and keep a different variable with the required number of zeroes. This will let the number keep its semantic meaning of the number as a number (and allow incrementing, as you said), and when displaying it, pad or fill with zeroes when needed, based on the second value.